# Question about data analysis and peak detection from txt file in python

Tags: python, python-3.x, numpy, matplotlib, scipy

So I am currently looking for advice on the best way to program python to detect the last minimum [temp] value in a text file before an exponential spike. The problem is the data proceeds so it spikes and then falls below that min value because there are 4 thermometers so I can use the normal min feature.

Plz let me know of any suggestions thank you
My part of my current code is bellow

```
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt




rawData = [line.rstrip() for line in open(".txt")]
x, y = [], []
for i in range(len(rawData)):
templist = rawData[i].split()
x.append(float(templist[0]))
y.append(float(templist[1]))
plt.plot(x, y, 'b', label= 'Tube 1 ', marker="*" )
plt.xlabel('Time (sec)')
plt.ylabel('Temperature ')


z = min(y) 
print('tube_1 temp=',z)
plt.show()
```

Comment: Can you update your question and add output figure and prints, please.